# Adding email to CC's while creating ticket on Zendesk via android app

Tags: android, zendesk

I am creating a ticket from my Android App. I want to add email id to the CC's field of the ticket created so that the ticket email also goes to that email id. But I am not able to figure out how I can achieve this. Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

The default setup of Zendesk only allows you to CC Agents.

So you have a couple of options:

1. Make every person you want to CC an agent (expensive and waste of licences)
2. Look at something like Zendesk Light agents. Have a chat with Zendesk about this, as i believe this is free if your an enterprise user otherwise take a look at the apps in the Zendesk store, there are a couple that can allow this.

[Understanding and setting light agent permissions (Professional Add-on and Enterprise Add-on)](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203662036-Understanding-and-setting-light-agent-permissions-Professional-Add-on-and-Enterprise-Add-on-)

Comment: Also Zendesk is restrictive about letter the email field be used, such as you can not generate a report to show the email address of the users who have logged a ticket. Best to talk to Zendesk directly about this, log a ticket with them, they are very good.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this by making the user as light agent which is free. triggers will help you to add cc to any ticket created. use option ticket is created as a condition and in action add CC, choose the user u want to CC.